# DATEDIFF wrong day result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have problem in using `DATEDIFF` in sql.

`DATEDIFF(DAY,@SimdikiTarih,DATEADD(YEAR,5,t.yenitarih)) AS KalanGun`

Here `@SimdikiTarih='10.06.2015'` date of today
and `t.yenitarih='03.04.2011'` (day.month.year)

The result is 298.
Won't it be 293?

Thank you!

Comment: Which dbms has DATEDIFF?

Comment: Why do You think that, the good result is 293?

Comment: timeanddate.com shows the difference as 298 days, as does my local Sybase ASE installation. What makes you think it's 293 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing 298 days, but still if you are not getting proper result then Try below query, Convert string to date.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(DATE,@SimdikiTarih,103),DATEADD(YEAR,5,CONVERT(DATE,t.yenitarih),103))) AS KalanGun
```